# Android JSON error (via PHP API) after MySQL foreign key relationship

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, foreign-key-relationship

I have an android app that sends data to a MySQL PHPMyAdmin table. The data stores in the database perfectly. I have two tables named `event` and `activity`. So I created a foreign key in `activity` that relates to the `eid` field in `event`. It shows the relation properly in the Designer section in PHPMyAdmin too. But the problem is, now I get a JSON error from the android application. I can't seem to figure out why. I added the code `db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");` in the `onCreate` method of the DBHelper class too. The error I get is the `json_encode` error response. Here's my php code for reference:

```
if ($tag == 'newAct'){

    $aName = $_POST['aname'];
    $aType = $_POST['atype'];
    $aDesc = $_POST['adesc'];
    $aSdate = $_POST['asdate'];
    $aEdate = $_POST['aedate'];
    $aStime = $_POST['astime'];
    $aEtime = $_POST['aetime'];
    $aGoal = $_POST['agoal'];
    $aLocation = $_POST['alocation'];
    $aCreated_by = $_POST['acreated_by'];

    //$subject = "New activity";
     //$message = "You have sucessfully created a new activity.\n\nRegards,\nAdmin.";
      //$from = "Shareity Team";
      //$headers = "From:" . $from;

    $activity = $db->addActivity($aName, $aType, $aDesc, $aSdate, $aEdate, $aStime, $aEtime, $aGoal, $aLocation, $aCreated_by);

    if ($activity) {
            // activity stored successfully
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["activity"]["aname"] = $activity["aname"];
        $response["activity"]["atype"] = $activity["atype"];
        $response["activity"]["adesc"] = $activity["adesc"];
        $response["activity"]["asdate"] = $activity["asdate"];
        $response["activity"]["aedate"] = $activity["aedate"];
        $response["activity"]["astime"] = $activity["astime"];
        $response["activity"]["aetime"] = $activity["aetime"];
        $response["activity"]["agoal"] = $activity["agoal"];
        $response["activity"]["alocation"] = $activity["alocation"];
        $response["activity"]["acreated_at"] = $activity["acreated_at"];
        $response["activity"]["aedited_at"] = $activity["aedited_at"];
        $response["activity"]["acreated_by"] = $activity["acreated_by"];
           //mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);

            echo json_encode($response);
        } 
        else {
            // activity failed to store
            $response["error"] = 1;
            $response["error_msg"] = "JSON Error occured in creating the activity WTF";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
```

This is the addActivity function

```
public function addActivity($aname, $atype, $adesc, $asdate, $aedate, $astime, $aetime, $agoal, $alocation, $acreated_by) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    //$hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    //$encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    //$salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO activity(aname, atype, adesc, asdate, aedate, astime, aetime, agoal, alocation, acreated_at, aedited_at, acreated_by) VALUES('$aname', '$atype','$adesc', '$asdate', '$aedate', '$astime', '$aetime', '$agoal', '$alocation', NOW(), NOW(),'$acreated_by')");
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
         //get event details 
        $activityid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        //$eventid = mysql_insert_id();
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM activity WHERE activityid = $activityid");
         //return event details
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. You're using `mysql_` which is deprecated. Consider using `PDO` or `mysqli_` instead. 2. Instead of returning `false` in your function, consider using `mysql_error()` to debug the query and use that returned variable in your json error message so you'll be able to see the error. (Just for debugging purpose of course)